# Trying to use lookup to find a field in VBA

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I think I am close I just don't know the exact syntax.

I am trying to use VBA to select a record based on the value of the SCID (Primary Key) from my table Stock Conversion.

```
If LookUp("Source PC", "Stock Conversion") Is Null Then
sc1.AddNew
sc1.Fields("[Source PC]").Value = Me.cmbSource.Value
sc1.Update
End If
```

This is the code I have now, as you can see I only want the field to be populated if the value is Null. It needs to find the Source PC where SCID = Record.

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you should use a recordset.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String

'SQL to select a record from a table MyTable based on a field or control
'called ID in the current form
sSQL="Select Id,Field1 from MyTable Where Id=" & Me.ID

'Open the recordset
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
'Test for End Of File to see if the recordset is empty ...
If rs.Eof Then
   'add a new record
   rs.AddNew 
   rs!Field1 = "Something"
   rs.Update
Else
   '... otherwise, do what you want with the record,
   'let us say edit.
   rs.edit
   rs!Field1 = "Something"
   rs.Update
End If
```

Comment: Hi Remou, is there any chance you could walk me through that code and what each piece does?

Comment: Brilliant, how does the Id, Field1 bit work in the first select statement? Would I just replace that with [Source PC]?

Comment: @BobP one key note is to explicitely define the `DAO` namespace....cause there are two different versions of the `Recordset` object.  There is an `DAO` and an `ADO`, so make sure you explicitely define `DAO`

Comment: Field1 is indeed any field you care to include in the sql statement.

Comment: Ahh ok, and what does Eof mean? I understand it is similar to NULL?

Comment: EOF means End Of File. With DAO it is safe enough to test for EOF to see if a recordset is empty. You also have BOF. It is not similar to null, it is a pointer.

Comment: So why wouldn't you just use if null? Sorry i'm just trying to get context

Comment: Because it is not null, it is an object. It is not empty either, as an object, it is just that the recordset that the object contains is empty.

Comment: Is your example above missing -- Dim sSQL as String -- ??

Comment: The code I post is nearly always just a sample. It does not begin with Function or Sub and it does not have any error trapping, so why pick on one fairly obvious variable? :) For that matter `Me.ID` will fall over if you do not put the code in a suitable module.

Comment: I was just checking because I wasn't sure whether it actually needed it or not >.<

Comment: VBA will run without any defined variables, you should not do it, hence `Option Explicit`, but you can. Similarly, you can run without error trapping, but you should not.